# How to use session in custom class laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

here is my code:

```
<?php 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
namespace App\CustomLibrary

{
    class myFunctions {
        public function is_login() {
            if(Session::get('id') != null){

                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I'm new in laravel 5, i just added a new custom function. And inside that function i wanna check a session ('id)? But i've got an error like this

> FatalErrorException in myFunctions.php line 8:
>   Class 'App\CustomLibrary\Session' not found

I need to know how to use session properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this clause to the top of the class, right after `namespace` part:

```
use Session;
```

Or use full namespace:

```
if (\Session::get('id') != null)
```

Or use the `session()` helper:

```
if (session('id') != null)
```

Comment: if (session('id') != null). i dont know there is a simple way like this. Thx @Alexey Mezenin

Answer (score 2):

Your `use` needs to be **after** the namespace declaration:

```
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session; //Not here
namespace App\CustomLibrary

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session; //Here
```

Anything that is `use`d before the namespace is used within the global namespace which changes once a namespace is declared.

Answer (score 1):

**use Session;** in Model and Controller

// Via a request instance...

**$request->session()->put('key', 'value');**

// Via the global helper...

**session(['key' => 'value']);**

for more details https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session