# How to use session in custom facade in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am new to Laravel and working on version 5.5. For my knowledge, I have created custom facade and now I am trying to set some session values into this facade as well as try to get the value of set session.

But Laravel is not able to set session in this custom facade. If I do the same thing in controller then it is working fine.

Below are my possible way that I have tried:

```
public function setUserSession() {  
   //Ist way
   session()->put('user', 'some values');
   var_dump(session()->has('user')); // this is returning me false  

   //2nd way  
   request()->session()->put('user', 'some values');  
   var_dump(request()->session()->has('user')); // this is returning me false 

   Session::set('user', 'some values');  //this is giving me error
   /* for above line I have include below namespace:  
      1.Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session  
   */  
   var_dump(Session::get('user')); // this is returning me false 
}
```

Even I have tried the solutions of below link:

[How to use session in custom class laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048945/how-to-use-session-in-custom-class-laravel-5)

But nothing change. Please anyone share your solution for this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Custom facade has nothing to do with session. Ensure the place where you call setUserSession() is in the route that applies `web` middleware because `web` middleware starts session service

Comment: Yes, I am calling this function from controller. And my controller route has web middleware as well as custom middleware. One more thing, the same thing I am trying in Laravel5.4 and it is working fine. i.e session is created in 5.4

Comment: what is your session driver, the problem may happen in cache system. BTW,  Session::set('user', 'some values') always returns error since there is no set method there